# Nagios core 4 Audio Alarms problem with firefox

Tags: linux, audio, firefox, nagios

i've searched everywhere for a solution but i start to think there's something i do not understand in the problem i've discovered on a nagios core installation.

I've configured audio alarms (beep and siren) on status change and if i open my Internet Explorer on a remote client everything is ok. So the configuration is correct. But if i open the same page with firefox there's no audio.

My goal is to let it work on a Centos 6.9 workstation that will be used to monitor the system and, sorry to say, it has firefox installed and we could not install any other kind of browser.

If i manually play the audio with aplay the internal speaker works, but there's no audio from Nagios. I've found some guides that suggested me to install nagios_checker but it is too old for the version of firefox i'm using. There's any other solution or idea on how to "fight" this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't give an answer, but I can suggest to you in using Firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nagios-checker/.

Comment: the nagios_checker does not work anymore on the new firefox versions... that's why i gave up with it...